# How to run a specific Jupyter cell number from the terminal?

Tags: python, cmd, terminal, jupyter-notebook

Let's say I have 10 Jupyter cells. Right now I use the command

`jupyter nbconvert --to notebook --execute --inplace mynotebook.ipynb`

to run my jupyter notebook. What can I do if I want to run just the 3rd cell for example, or the 5 the cell? Thanks for the help